# add input type upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, append

I am trying to add an  type upon clicking the button.

Here is my jquery script:

```
$(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
  $("#inputboxes").append("<tr class='light'><td colspan='3' class='header'>Subject Name</td><td colspan='3'><input type='text' name='subject_name' /></td></tr>");
  })
});
```

Then my HTML markup:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:center;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7">Add subject on the list of available subjects</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody id="inputboxes">
        <tr class="dark">
            <td colspan="7">
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Click to add a subject" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr class="dark">
        <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

#on page top
if(isset($_GET['submit']) print_r($_GET); // the only entry of array is the [submit'] => "Submit"
```

I can successfully generate an  box, however it seems that whenever I hit submit, the  box doesn't seem to be passed. Also how can I generate an increment in the name="" of generated  box.

**For the record, I found the workaround for this, moved the form tag outside of the table. Thanks everyone.**

Comment: Is this not working for you? What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I edited my post, I accidentally submitted the question without having finishing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the submit button to work, you need to put your inputs in a form. You can add an increment in the name if you want to, but it is not necessary. If you submit inputs with the same name, they will be submitted as an array.

Adding increment:

```
$(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#inputboxes").append("<tr class='light'><td colspan='3' class='header'>Subject Name</td><td colspan='3'><input type='text' name='subject_name" + (i++) + "' /></td></tr>");
    })
});
```

Adding form:

```
<form action="url" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tbody id="inputboxes">
            <tr class="dark">
                <td colspan="7"><input type="button" id="add" value="Click to add a subject" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="dark">
                <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I used get as method of the form, edited my question. Thanks for the incrementing of name on generated box.

Comment: Why don't you initialize i with zero?

Comment: @Dee are you still having problems submitting the inputs? Bergi, You can if you want, I just chose to initialize i with one.

Comment: I just now. Thanks William. I moved the <form> outside of the <table>, this fix the issue. Inputs are now submitted properly.